# mysql breakdown of group sum amount

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get a group on each sum to create each new columns.

```
SELECT 
    distinct settlement_id,

    SUM(amount) AS `Order`,
    SUM(amount) AS `Refund`,
    SUM(amount) AS `Servicefee`,
    SUM(amount) AS `other_Transaction`

FROM
    settlements
WHERE
    transaction_type = 'order'
        OR transaction_type = 'refund'
        OR transaction_type = 'ServiceFee'
        OR transaction_type = 'other-transaction'

GROUP BY settlement_id ASC ,  transaction_type ASC
```

As results are not what I'm looking for 
[image: workbench screenshot]

This is a kind of result like the screenshot below, that is what I am looking for
[image: excel screenshot]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include all data directly in the question?

Comment: Ok I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` and `IF` together to achieve this.

```
SELECT settlement_id, 
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'order',amount,0)) AS 'Order',
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'refund',amount,0)) AS 'Refund',
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'ServiceFee',amount,0)) AS 'Servicefee',
    SUM(IF(transaction_type = 'other-transaction',amount,0)) AS 'other_Transaction'
FROM settlements
GROUP BY settlement_id
```